# Having trouble with the php command "imagepng" creating a file with unique name

Tags: php

Hello I am having trouble getting imagepng to not only create a image on my server but name it a specific name according to a POST input from a form on another page.

It will display the finished image on screen just fine but depending on which method I try (tried many), it either creates a file name ".png" or does not create one at all.

Here is the "form.html" the info is pulling from:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post"><BR><BR>
Type Forum Name:
<input type="text" name="name" value=""/><BR><BR>
<input type="submit" name="Submit1"><BR><BR>
</form><BR>
```

And here is "test.php":

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];

$input1 = $_POST["fsbg"];

$input2 = $_POST["rank"];

header ("Content-type: image/png");
$background = imagecreatefrompng($fsbg);
$pkt = imagecreatefromgif($rank);
imagecopymerge($background,$pkt,260,136,0,0,55,55,100);
imagepng($background);
$save = strtolower($name) .".png";
imagepng($background, $save);
imagedestroy($background);
imagedestroy($pkt);
header('location:link.php');
?>
```

I have set folder/sub folder permissions to 777, tried saving in the same path as the file, as well as saving in a sub folder called "pvt".

Any help/Advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `$save = "../pvt/". strtolower($name) .".png";` might be your problem, sometimes using relative paths with `..` isn't allowed. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what got submitted to the server? `var_dump($save)` to see what file name/path you're building? imagepng() doesn't care what filename you provide -  it'll just be passed on to `fopen` internally anyways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: shortened example code for Philtune. To: dan08 ~ No sir I am not.. not in the codes present state. No change removing the ".." or even if I save the file in the same path as the "test.php" To: Marc B ~ Not quite sure how to do that... Ill read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a "name" field in the form. You have a unnamed field whose value is "name":

```
<input type="text" value="name"/><BR><BR>
```

Needs to be:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="name"/><BR><BR>
```

Also, when you do this, sanitize the input. What if I sent you name="../../etc/passwd" or something like that? (*of course this example won't work. But still.*).

At the very least use `basename` to strip all path components from the name, and `realpath` to ensure you're writing where you should.

Comment: Thats embarassing, Thanks for that but it didnt fix it. Thought that might have been it too, darn. Its still ouputs a image file with no name like this".png". I corrected the error on the form, changed it to save in the same path as the code file but still wont apply the user inputed name to the file. Also I realize this code isnt secure I'm just trying to get it to work first.

Comment: Try checking the output of getcwd () and the final file save name. It might be that your script is not running from the directory you think.nor

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.

Turns out even though I was changing the Permissions in my FTP, I still needed to add this in to get it to save a file: chmod($name,0755);

Completed code looks like:

```
$background = imagecreatefrompng($fsbg);
$pkt = imagecreatefromgif($rank);
//$pkt2 = imagecreatefromgif($rank);
imagecopymerge($background,$pkt,260,136,0,0,55,55,100);
//imagecopymerge($background,$pkt2,290,136,0,0,55,55,100);
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng($background);
$name = $filename.".png";
chmod($name,0755);
imagepng($background, $name);
imagedestroy($background);
imagedestroy($pkt);
```

Thanks to all who tooks the time to reply.